# groupby ideal strategy in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading data using Spark Streaming from a Kafka Source, from where I create a dataframe with columns `wsid`, `year`, `month`, `day`, `oneHourPrecip`:

```
val df = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("subscribe", "raw_weather")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<host1:port1,host2:port2>...")
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism" , "PLAIN")
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"token\" password=\"" + "<some password>" + "\";")
    .option("kafka.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2")
    .option("kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols", "TLSv1.2")
    .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "HTTPS")
    .load()
    .selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")
    .as[String]
    .withColumn("_tmp", split(col("value"), "\\,"))
    .select(
        $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("wsid"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("year").cast("int"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("month").cast("int"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(3).as("day").cast("int"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(11).as("oneHourPrecip").cast("double")
    )
    .drop("_tmp")
```

I then perform a groupby and then try to write this stream data into a table using JDBC. For that purpose, this is my code:

```
val query= df.writeStream
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
    .foreachBatch((df: DataFrame , id: Long) => {
        println(df.count())
        df.groupBy($"wsid" , $"year" , $"month" , $"day")
            .agg(sum($"oneHourPrecip").as("precipitation"))
            .write
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .jdbc(url , s"$schema.$table" , getProperties)
    })
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1))
    .start()
```

The problem comes with the batch. With Spark Streaming, we cannot predict the number of rows that come every batch in a dataframe. So quite a lot of times, I get data that is disjointed (ie. for the given common values `(wsid,year,month,day)`, some rows appear in one batch while some others appear in another batch).

Then when I groupby and try to write it using JDBC, this is the error I get:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.25.13] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:502)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.endBatchedReadChain(Agent.java:434)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.a(k4.java:5452)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.c(k4.java:5026)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.executeBatch(k4.java:3058)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Error for batch element #1: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1;SPARK.DAILY_PRECIPITATION_DATA, DRIVER=4.25.13
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:806)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:66)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:140)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:1283)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:128)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:57)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.aw.a(aw.java:225)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.a(k4.java:3605)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.d(k4.java:6020)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.a(k4.java:5372)
        ... 17 more
```

As evident from the `SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException` above, it is because after one batch writes the `groupby`ed values using JDBC, insertion for the next set of values fail because of the primary key `(wsid,year,month,day)`.

Given that there will be a fixed number of `oneHourPrecip` values (24) for  a given `(wsid,year,month,day)` from the source, how do we ensure that groupBy works properly for all data that is streamed from the source, so that insertion into Database is not a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure something out, but this may have some performance concerns. Anyways, it worked for me so am posting the answer:

I figured out that in order to store a `groupby`ed data into a DB2 table, we would have to wait until we retrieve all the data from the source. For that, I utilize `OutputMode.Complete()`.

Then I realized if I were to write it into DB2 after grouping in the current method, it would still throw me the same error. For that, I had to use `SaveMode.Overwrite` inside `foreachBatch`.

I tried running my program with this approach, but it threw this error:

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets`

So I decided to do groupby and aggregation during `readStream` itself. Thus my code looks like this:

`readStream` part:

```
val df = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("subscribe", "raw_weather")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<host1:port1,host2:port2>...")
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism" , "PLAIN")
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"token\" password=\"" + "<some password>" + "\";")
    .option("kafka.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2")
    .option("kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols", "TLSv1.2")
    .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "HTTPS")
    .load()
    .selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")
    .as[String]
    .withColumn("_tmp", split(col("value"), "\\,"))
    .select(
        $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("wsid"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("year").cast("int"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("month").cast("int"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(3).as("day").cast("int"),
        $"_tmp".getItem(11).as("oneHourPrecip").cast("double")
    )
    .drop("_tmp")
    .groupBy($"wsid" , $"year" , $"month" , $"day")
    .agg(sum($"oneHourPrecip").as("precipitation"))
```

`writeStream` part:

```
val query= df.writeStream
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
    .foreachBatch((df: DataFrame , id: Long) => {
        println(df.count())
        df.write
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .jdbc(url , s"$schema.$table" , getProperties)
    })
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1))
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: savemode overwrite will overwrite data but your requirement is to update the data right ?

Comment: No, all I required is to get data from source, run a groupby and then save it to the database, irrespective of the method used

Comment: since you are using overwrite there is no constraint violation. nothing to do with grouping here. and nothing special you are doing here... I thought you are looking for update if row is already present. thats the reason I suggested upsert. moreover your question showed '.mode(SaveMode.Append)' .....  just replace overwrite with append you will understand why you are getting constraint violation in  your code. Hope you understood

Comment: Got it. But I was looking for ideal groupBy strategies with Append mode itself, until I went through Overwrite

Answer (score 1):

***`SaveMode.Upsert`*** is not available :-)
There is nothing to do with `groupBy`. group by just groups the values. integrity violation (*`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException`*) you need to take care at sql level.

***Option 1:***

You can do insert update  to avoid integrety violation.

for this you need to use like below pseudo code...

```
dataframe.foreachPartition {

update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME=xxxxx where MyID=XXX;

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME values (colid,col1,col2) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from TABLE_NAME where colid=xxxx);
}
```

***Option 2 :***
or check [merge statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) in db2

one way is create a empty temp table ( with out any connstraints) which has same schema  and populate it and at the end you can execute a script which will merge in to the target
table.

Comment: So is there no way where we can do a groupby in spark streaming as and when the data comes, or have partitions defined for readStream/writeStream inside spark, then do a foreachPartition?

Comment: if you get dataframe you can do groupby and resultant df you can do foreachpartitions